# How Can I Set Mac OS X's Finder Default Window Size

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, finder

I wish to configure Finder.app so that the default window size is larger then the default. If I resize a window that displays a folder, next time I open that folder with Finder, the window size would be the one that I used the last time I viewed that folder with Finder. This setting seems to be kept in the **hidden** `.DS_Store` file in each directory I view.

I wish I could modify Finder's initial window size without opening each possible folder. Where is this setting kept?

I use Mac OS X 10.6.x (Cocoa Finder.app, if that is an issue).

Thanks,

Comment: I haven’t found a way to do this in years of searching, but I would love it if there was. Currently I use a preset in MercuryMover.

Answer (score 2):

The only "real" answer to this issue that I have seen is to click on the Finder in the dock.  When the window opens, immediately resize that window and close it.  Don't move files, etc, simply close the window.  Now each opened window will reflect the same size as the original.  By all means, this is a 'hack' and it isn't something permanent.  If you open your Finder windows via command + n do the same as above to set the size.

Comment: This only sets the window size for whichever folder opens by default (probably your home folder); it does not set a universal default window size. Folders which you have never viewed before will not inherit this window size. (To see what I mean, try running “open /System/Library/Graphics/Quartz\ Composer\ Plug-Ins/WOTD.plugin/Contents/” in Terminal.)

Comment: Ah, I'm still on Mojave/10.14 and it still exists and works. You must be on Catalina?

Answer (score 2):

Open a finder window and size it how you want it. Then go to View->Show View Options and click "Use as defaults". When you open a new Finder window, it will have that look-n-feel.

[image]

Comment: That button doesn't seem to exist anymore (Mojave). Not sure what the new behavior is.